# Java ssl with BufferedWriter and binary data

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl, binary-data

The problem is solved, see below...

I am currently developing a server-client application.

The server is programmed in C/C++ using openssl and the client is programmed in android-java using the SSLSocket class.
To write to the SSL-socket (client) I am using the BufferefWriter.
I guess that is the main problem, but my research for my problem or for alternatives was not of success...

This is how I write data to the socket:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true));
// This was a typo char[] data = new byte[] {0,0,0,255};
char[] data = new char[] {0,0,0,255};
out.write(data);
```

Now the server recieves `0,0,195,191`
And that really confuses me!

But I guess it is due to the way the BufferedWriter works.

So what can I do in order to send binary data to the SSL socket?
What alternatives are there to the BufferedWriter?

Thanks for your time!

**SOLVED**

Ok thanks to McDowell and robermann I found the following sollution:

```
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
byte[] data = new byte[] {0,0,0,255};
out.write(data);
```

I didn't know about the way java works with chars and thus was kind of confused.
For further information about the way chars are used in java take a look at McDowell's answer below.

Thanks to all you guys! :D

Comment: Why are you confused? Anyway, you could write to a ByteArrayOutputStream

Comment: This won't compile: `char[] data = new byte[]...` - correct your code. Remember that a _char_ is 16bits wide and the _PrintWriter_ is performing a transcoding operation from UTF-16 to the platform encoding. A Java _char_ is more like a _wchar_t_; the Java _byte_ is an 8bit type with the same width as a C _char_.

Comment: @Ch33f Maybe were you expecting to see encrypted data on the server?

Comment: @McDowell The char = new byte thing was a typo but I didn't know that char is 16-bit wide in java, well that explains a lot! Thanks! I'll try the ByteArrayOutputStram

Comment: 'BufferedWriter and binary data' is already a major programming error. If you have binary data, or you *don't* know that you definitely have character data, you must use streams, not readers and writers.

Answer (score 2):

```
char[] data = new char[] {0,0,0,255};
```

*char* values are implicitly UTF-16BE. The default encoding on Android is UTF-8. For the given constructor the [PrintWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintWriter.html) will perform a transcoding operation from UTF-16 to UTF-8.

The above values should become the 5-byte sequence `00 00 00 c3 bf` which (bar a leading byte) you are seeing on the server.

Types like [DataOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) or something more formal (like [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview)) may be more suitable for low-level binary protocols.